# Program to find the maximum occuring email in a file in python

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, get

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    bigcount=0
    bigword=None
    line=line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From'):
        words=list()
        words=line.split()
        word=words[1]
        count=dict()
        count[word]=count.get(word,0)+1
    for i,j in count.items():
       if j>bigcount:
            bigcount=j
            bigword=i
print(bigword,bigcount)
```

I am getting the maximum occuring word but is not getting it's correct corresponding frequency. Please help me in spotting the error in this particular code

Comment: Are you asking us to help *debug* without any *sample* input?  That's quite hard...

Comment: Hi @MohitKumar, and welcome to StackOverflow! As Daniel said, please post an example `mbox-short.txt`, the output of your program, and the desired output. It would help us help you better!

Answer (score 1):

I'm never good at debugging other's code, because it's *double labor* *(try to think like others...)*  So instead of doing it, let's present a short working version.  (Done it n+ years ago...)
Hopefully, you can read and compare then figure it out what's wrong yourself.  It's a good learning practice too.

```py
fname = input("Enter file name")
fh = open(fname)
counts = {}
lst = []

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    line = line.rstrip().split()
    emails = line[1]
    lst.append(emails)
for email in lst:
    counts[email] = counts.get(email, 0) +1
print(emails, counts[email])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
if line.startswith('From'):
```

with

```
if line.startswith('From:'): continue
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Add this line at the place shown above and try. Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need to add comments to your answer to add info. Edit your answer and add whatever additional text is needed. On that note, I suggest you add some more detail on how your post helps the answer the question. As it is there is not enough detail and you might risk it being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest using the ancient method of printing out values at various places in your code, to confirm if it is or is not doing what you expect or intend.  Debuggers are good for this also.  Also, create a couple different input files, small, random, to see how it behaves with different input.  This can reveal a lot.

You say you are getting the maximum occurring word.  I highly suspect this is because it's the last word in your input file.  Rearrange your input data, so that it is not the last input line, and see what results you get.

And finally, here's your bug:  Line 13: "count=dict()".  You're re-initializing the dictionary every time you intend to add a value to it.  Hoist that above your first 'for line in handle:' loop, I expect you'll see a big difference.

PS: perhaps not a bug, but a waste of effort.  You're indexing through the dictionary every time you add a count.  Just do it once after all the data is read it.  In other words, outdent 'for i,j in count.items():' so that loop runs just once after the data is tallied.  It won't produce a different result, but it'll stop wasting effort.